# After long journeys, gear slips in 5th, but not into neutral

Tags: clutch, car, manual-transmission, gears

[This is a follow up to another question I asked.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/18779/11481) I've managed to get some [video](https://youtu.be/J8U1DT7pXIQ) of it happening this time.

It started happening after travelling for about 2 hours. I was experiencing heavy traffic.

The last time this happened was after I was driving for an extended period of time. It never happens when I'm commuting to and from work. For the last two weeks it has been fine.

Additionally, the gear only slips out after accelerating, and in the 2900-3000rpm range.

When the gear does slip out, the car doesn't coast as if it's in neutral. The car doesn't merely lose momentum either; something is actively slowing the car down.

I have a VW Polo 2001, 1.4 engine, manual, petrol. It has done ~37,000 miles. It passed MOT in June; serviced in July with replacement timing belt; new clutch in July.

My questions:

1. Is it worth replacing my car?
2. What precautions should I take?
3. Is it the clutch or the gearbox?
4. I have warranty on my clutch; if it is the gearbox, how much is a replacement?
5. If it is the gearbox, is there any possibility of damage to my clutch?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are experiencing is usually a sign the synchro for that gear is or is going bad.

> 1. Is it worth replacing my car?

Only if you can afford it. Fixing the transmission is going to be way less expensive than replacing the entire vehicle.

> 2. What precautions should I take?

If you need to drive it, just hold the stick in place for that gear. You would, in effect, be doing the work for the synchro to hold it in gear.

> 3. Is it the clutch or the gearbox?

This is more than likely synchros in the gearbox, not the clutch.

> 4. I have warranty on my clutch; if it is the gearbox, how much is a replacement?

That depends on your locality. I'm not able to answer it for you due to this.

> 5. If it is the gearbox, is there any possibility of damage to my clutch?

Not usually, unless there was damage to it in the first place.

> 6. Is it worth replacing my car?

You asked this already, so ...

Comment: Sorry about question 1 and 6! I was typing it on my phone. If by locality you mean country, I'm in the south of England. I'm thinking of getting a reconditioned gearbox fitted.

Comment: @MiKenning - What I'm saying about #4 is, that's a shopping question which is off-topic. It doesn't make sense to answer it because the cost would be local to you and does not work for everyone on the net.

Comment: Ah I see! Fair enough. I'll do some browsing. Thanks for the answer!